# How to slice a value present in dataframe column

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe and column in dataframe is "CarName"
the value is "polo allstar"

Now, I have to split the value "polo allstar" based on space, and replace the value in CarName to "polo".

Need help.

Comment: You should be able to use `split`.

Answer (score 0):

You can `map` over the column with the `split` function and take the first word:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'CarName': ['polo allstar']})
print(df)

df.CarName = df.CarName.map(lambda cn: cn.split()[0])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        CarName
0  polo allstar

  CarName
0    polo
```